# RTMP -> endoce using ffmpeg -> HLS,DASH

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp

I would like to do "RTMP -> endoce using ffmpeg -> HLS,DASH".

```
・OS: CentOS7
・nginx version: nginx/1.13.0
　with nginx-rtmp-module
・ffmpeg
ffmpeg version N-83692-gb8a7dcbde2-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.1 (Debian 5.4.1-5) 20170205
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-5 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      55. 47.100 / 55. 47.100
  libavcodec     57. 81.100 / 57. 81.100
  libavformat    57. 66.102 / 57. 66.102
  libavdevice    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
  libavfilter     6. 74.100 /  6. 74.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100

/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
rtmp {
  server {
      listen 1935;
      application test {
        live on;
        exec /root/ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/test/$name
        -b:v 1000k -r 30 -s 720x480 -c:v libx264 -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/$name_low;
      }
      application live {
        live on;
        hls  on;
        hls_path /usr/local/nginx/html/hls;
        hls_fragment 10s;
        hls_type live;
        dash on;
        dash_path /usr/local/nginx/html/dash;
      }
  }
}
```

When I tried "rtmp://domain.com/live/test1", it was success. There are some segment on hls and dash folder.

But, When I teird "rtmp://domain.com/test/test2", it was fail.

In error.log

2017/07/01 22:02:03 [alert] 23951#0: unknown process 24019 exited on signal 9

What wrong is setting? If you know the cause of problem, let me know how to resolve it.